# vagrant puppetlabs-mysql Mysql_grant failed

Tags: vagrant, puppet, puppetlabs-mysql

I want to use vagrant, and I defined the following puppet file:
http://pastebin.com/GfJK1ziS

When vagrant tries to install the modules everything works as expected. But when it tries to configure `mysql`, it always get this error:

```
 Error: Validation of Mysql_grant[${username}@%/${db_name}.*] failed: name must match user and table parameters
```

What can I do?

As far as I can tell its due to this line in `puppetlabs_mysql` module

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql/commit/07b661dcea926981cf5cd1c703a1c982d6eb6ef1

i don't know what i have to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with `mysql_grants` definition.
It fails on the following test:

```
fail('name must match user and table parameters') if self[:name] != "#{self[:user]}/#{self[:table]}"
```

Error message exactly explains what is wrong. Name of grant resource must match `user` and `table`. 
So change:

```
  '${username}@%/${db_name}.*' => {
    ...
    table      => "${db_name}.*",
    user       => "${username}@%",
  }
```

to

```
  "${username}@%/${db_name}.*" => {
    ...
    table      => "${db_name}.*",
    user       => "${username}@%",
  }
```

[Single quoted](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#single-quoted-strings) strings does not interpolate variables in puppet.

**UPDATE:**
There are also a lot of style issues. You are mixing single quotes strings, with double quotes strings. Use [puppet-lint](http://puppet-lint.com/) to improve the style of your code.